# Spring: which starts before the other, the listener or the bean

Tags: spring

I have a **class A** which extends **ContextLoaderListener**, and it's added to the web.xml in a `<listener>` tag.

In other part, I have a **class B** which implements InitializingBean, this class is used as the target_object of **org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean** (used for the Spring quartz Job)

My Question is, how can I ensure that the class A starts before the class B?

Comment: Why do you need that exactly the listener starts before your bean? Please describe a bit more of what the dependencies between them are  - sounds like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378) to me.

Comment: i wanna that my listener starts the first , cause I will set by myself the cronExpression of my cronTriggerBean.